# Adding custom HTTP post parameters to the swagger docs generated from baucis

Tags: baucis

I'm trying to add a parameter to the swagger docs that are generated with baucis. The parameter gets added to the list of params, but it doesn't show up in the swagger-ui.

Any ideas?

```
mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);

// Create the API routes
var baucisController = baucis.rest('Image');

for (var i = 0; i < baucisController.swagger.apis.length; i++) {
    var apis = [baucisController.swagger.apis[i]];

    for (var j = 0; j < apis.length; j++) {
        var api = apis[j];

        if (api.path == '/Images') {

            for (var k = 0; k < api.operations.length; k++) {
                var operation = api.operations[k];

                if (operation["httpMethod"] == "POST") {                    

                    operation["parameters"].push({
                        "name": "image",
                        "description": "The image.",
                        "paramType": "body",
                        "required": true,
                        "allowMultiple": false,
                        "dataType": "file"
                    });

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of baucis?

Answer (score 0):

Did you call to `baucisController.generateSwagger();` before adding your extension? This command populates the default settings for your `baucisController.swagger`.
If called later, it can override your custom definitions.